# Force a file or image to download using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, download

I have been trying to force images to download using PHP Headers but there have been multiple problems.

So, instead, how can I use `.htaccess` so that when I link to an image like:

```
<a href="wallpapers/image.jpg">Download</a>
```

...instead of opening that file in browser, the file is actually downloaded and saved to the user's computer.

I am already using .htaccess in my project to rewrite URLs if that affects anything.

Comment: What were the problems with the PHP headers?

Comment: I think this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010636/force-link-to-mp3-file-to-download-save-as/1010663#1010663

Comment: @Grillz: tried that already after googling.. not working... @Evan PHP was making images but not not displaying them... if you have cent percent error proof code then be my guest

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put this into your .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:jpg|gif|png)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Make sure you have `mod_headers` installed and enabled.

Comment: Do you have mod_headers installed and activated?

Comment: HIT... installed & activated (now)