# Force download image

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to force the download of an image. I have found this code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:jpg|gif|png)$">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

but I have a special requirement. My images have an extension like `.png`

```
<a target="_blank" id="save_to_pc" href="/image.php?width=720&amp;height=480&amp;file=files/galleries/1549/01a750273f66cd8637bcd2811a34a3e5.jpg&amp;nocrop=1"></a>
```

can someone help me to filter this image and let the user download it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force File(image) Download with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218466/force-fileimage-download-with-htaccess)

Comment: @Fincha: Time to learn what a header is and how that works in Apache *or* PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by providing `Content-Disposition` in the header information of your image.php.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<your image filename>"');
```