# django - render a file of a model to template

Tags: python, django, file, render

I have a model called Advertisement. This model has text field, title field, and file field.

I am successfully saving all 3 of these fields into the model.

Now I need to show them in template. My vision is:

```
ads = Advertisement.objects.all()
return render_to_response('page.html', {'ads':ads},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in my page.html:

```
{% for each_ad in ads %}
<p>{{each_ad.title}}</p>
<p>{{each_ad.text}}</p>
<p><a href="/ads/{{each_ad.file_pdf}}>{{each_ad.file_pdf.name}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Does this seem right?  If not, please show me the way so I can learn. Thanks!

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Render the PDF inside the HTML page?

Comment: YES!! :D. i just want pdf to be downloadable. i will update my code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the PDF link downloads depends on the browser of the user.

Adding `target="_blank"` will open the pdf in a new window/tab though:

```
<p><a href="/ads/{{each_ad.file_pdf}}" target="_blank">{{each_ad.file_pdf.name}}</a></p>
```

To ensure that it always downloads in every environment is more difficult, you would need to set your `.htaccess` (if you're using apache, per something like this: [Force a file or image to download using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218466/force-fileimage-download-with-htaccess)) or force it as an `attachment` in producing the PDF from Django.

Comment: i am not trying to render the whole html page as pdf! this is not what i want. i just want to render pdf file to html page so that user can click and download the pdf file. nothing more

Comment: okay thanks, opening or downloading the pdf is almost same, so opening is also fine. so my vision-code is okay?