# How can I make a url a download link in html?

Tags: html, url

A client wants a `url` to be a download link.

**Use case is like so**:

user gets linked to `example.com/download` once there, it downloads a pdf file.

Can I do this without **php** ?

Comment: example.com/download/abc.pdf

Comment: would that link directly to the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How a file is displayed is browser specific. Some may force you to download while some directly render it on the browser.

If you want to force the browser to download the file then you can set in Header the

<del>`Content-Type : application/octet-stream`</del>

`Content-Disposition: attachment;`

Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Adding that tag to the whole page might yield undesirable results if there are links to files that shouldn't be downloaded directly. However it would work very well on a page with no other link than the PDF file.

Comment: The header is to be set on the link that returns the file. Eg: `download/asdf.pdf` should have the header set.

Comment: Isnt it `Content-Disposition: attachment;` to force download files ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d you are right.

Answer (score 6):

HTML5 introduced the [`download` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download).

Supporting user-agents will offer to download the file `foo.png` when clicking this link:

```
<a href="foo.png" download>Save the image</a>
```

You can also specify a different default file name that should be used:

```
<a href="foo.png" download="image.png>Save the image</a>
```

Read more at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#downloading-resources.

Note that this only works for **links**. When users enter the URL directly into their browsers, this will have no effect, of course. If you want that, you need to send specific HTTP headers. See for example the question: [How to force download of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/531292/1591669). You don’t necessarily need a programming language like PHP for that. You can do it with, for example, `.htaccess`, too: [Force File(image) Download with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4218466/1591669)

Answer (score 3):

You only need a link (anchor tag). The way the link behaves on click will depend on what browser you are and what settings you have in that particular browser. Some browsers will prompt you to open or save the file, other browsers will open the PDF file on a new tab or window.

```
<a href="path/to/your/file.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

You'll also need to make sure that the path to the PDF file is correct on the `href` property of your anchor tag.

Comment: The problem here is that browsers can render the PDF file instead show the download popup

Answer (score 2):

Use this (HTML) not PHP:

```
<a href="http://example.com/download/asdf.pdf">Download pdf</a>
```

Comment: In most of the browsers this will not download, instead it gives a preview of PDF. If you want to force download you need to set headers

Answer (score 1):

Use the full url including the pdf file like.

```
<a href="http://example.com/download/file.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```