# Give hyperlink to download image without image name

Tags: html, image

I am using QR code API from [this website](https://api.qrserver.com). It generates QR code image from the URL input we give to it. For example, I am showing the QRCode of data 'abcd' on my website by adding an `<img>` tag of `src=https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=abcd`. This shows the QR on screen, but I also want to give a download link to that image. Suppose if a user clicks on that image, it should get downloaded. How to do that? I am confused because the image is getting generated dynamically and I dont have a name or specific url to it.

Comment: Perhaps including an `<a>` tag with the href of src of the img tag?

Comment: @Atutouato tried but that didn't work. It loaded the image in browser but didn't download it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a url a download link in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174327/how-can-i-make-a-url-a-download-link-in-html)

Comment: @unor, this is not a duplicate.  Tigerden does not have any control over the Content-Type attribute of the headers of the qrserver site, so they can't use that solution.

Comment: @Atutouato: Well, the question is a duplicate (no matter which answer got accepted), isn’t it? Btw, other answers suggest  alternatives that don’t need changing HTTP headers.

Comment: @unor, OK, never mind.