# PHP-Image not downloading in safari and iphones

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to download images in iphone. It appears to be opening in a new window rather than downloading inside Chrome and Firefox etc.anybody any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094489/image-is-downloading-in-chrome-but-not-in-safari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image is downloading in chrome but not in safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094489/image-is-downloading-in-chrome-but-not-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

> Please check your mime type...may be it will help you.

```
$mimetypes = array(
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpg' => 'image/jepg',
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'css' => 'text/css',
    'js' => 'application/x-javascript'
);
```