# htaccess: alternative to using <if>?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to provide a button on a webpage that can optionally  cause an image file to be downloaded and stored in the client's filesystem. I thought to use the approach from [Force a file or image to download using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218466/force-fileimage-download-with-htaccess)
and wrote in my .htaccess, following the style of [the Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if),

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /download/">
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</If>
```

I then provide a link like http://www.example.com/images/image123.jpeg?download=true, and that works fine with my production server. But it gives me an `error 500` on the Mac development system on my desk, using either OS/X's apache or MAMP. Apache complains it does not understand the `<If>` statement, and [serverFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/340977/if-directive-not-working-in-apache-virtualhost-conf-says-invalid-command) tells me that  is not understood by Apache 2.2. Both OS/X and MAMP provide Apache 2.2.

Is there a way I can rewrite the `<if>` statement to produce the same effect in Apache 2.2, please?

I can't just use

```
<a download="clientFileName.jpg" href="/images/image123.jpeg">Download</a>
```

because it doesn't work in either IE11 or Safari.

Comment: Use a server side programming language. Like PHP

Comment: I initially, successfully, provided this with PHP, but now image sizes are in the hundreds of megabytes. The PHP process is forcefully terminated by the  hosting service for running too long. I cannot extend the allowed runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an env variable using rewrite rule first:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)download=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DL:1,L]
```

Then use this env variable in **conditionally** setting up your header:

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment env=DL
```

Comment: That looks very promising, it does seem to work. Now, if only I could understand the syntax...! Give me a few minutes here.

Comment: Yes, that definitely does work, after I had read enough of the Apache documentation to understand what you were saying. Thanks very much!