# Prompt user to download PDF file instead of opening

Tags: php, javascript, apache

In my project site, if I click on a link, the PDF opens in a new or parent window. Well I want a box to appear that prompts the user to download the file instead of opening it.

Does anyone know of a simple JavaScript onClick event that will do this, in all browsers, with default settings?

My server is PHP based.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your edit states that you're using PHP, here's how to do the same in PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: i want to enable this thing for all pdf on site not for any specfic pdf

Comment: It's helpful to include the file's size too, or the browser will likely say something "unknown" for the size/time left to download. `header('Content-Length: 12345');`

Answer (score 9):

Since you've tagged it .NET, I'd say this is your best solution:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.pdf");
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/files/myFile.pdf"));
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the Content-Type to application/octet-stream.  You may find however, that some browsers will infer from the file extension that it should open as a PDF with your favorite PDF viewer.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Also, set the following:

```
Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it via javascript, you need server side implementation.

Here's the SO Post which should help:
[Allowing user to download from my site through Response.WriteFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024910/allowing-user-to-download-from-my-site-through-response-writefile)

Answer (score 1):

http://aspalliance.com/259_Downloading_Files__Forcing_the_File_Download_Dialog

Comment: the required code from the article:

    Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + name );

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a corrupted file error try this:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); // provide file size
header('Connection: close');
readfile($file);
```

Where `$file` is the full **path or url** of the file.