# Force Open/Save dialog for inline PDF?

Tags: pdf, dialog, inline

I'm wondering if it is possible to force an Open/Save dialog for an inline PDF?

I have a link that opens a new window with an inline PDF in it. I was able to prompt the dialog by changing registry settings, but only if I changed my preferences in Adobe Reader (Internet > uncheck 'Display PDF in Browser'). So basically if the PDF is opening in Reader I can get a dialog.. but is this possible for inline PDFs? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change "Content-disposition" attribute of the header of your http respose accordingly.

- [This answer in SO tells you how to do it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590543/force-browser-to-download-pdf-document-instead-of-opening-it)
- [This one tells you how to do it in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804446/prompt-user-to-download-pdf-file-instead-of-opening)
- [This one in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974734/how-to-make-files-download-instead-of-opening-in-browser)

Comment: The C# link is not an answer to ***inline*** PDFs but to ***attachment*** PDFs