# Javascript for saving link using ctrl+s

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks on image link, it should prompt save option (instead of right click and save). I found ways to alert the user if he press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>s</kbd>. But how do I show an save option when he click the link. Below is my code which is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
   if  (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 115)
   {
       event.keyCode = 0;
   }
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manually open a save-as prompt in Javascript. The only thing you could do is change the window's location to the image, which you serve with special headers from the server. For example:

```
<img onclick="saveFunction()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveFunction() {
        window.location.href = this.getAttribue('src') + '?somethingspecial';
    };
</script>
```

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804446/prompt-user-to-download-pdf-file-instead-of-opening) to see how to serve a file to prompt as download. Looks like you need to set the `Content-Disposition` header with whatever web server you are using.