# Link to retrieve pdf file from DB- in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, pdf, file-upload

I have retrieved the pdf file from Database and linked it to a "a href" tag to open pdf file using link. Now I want to give the open/save dialog box before a pdf file opened . - in  javascript(by using **onclick** event in "a" tag to call the javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the **content-disposition** header using C# to get this behavior in a browser.

Read this for more info

[How do I prompt a "Save As" dialog for an accepted mime type?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-prompt-a-save-as-dialog-for-an-accepted-mime-type.html)

[Downloading a File with a Save As Dialog in ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx)

***Example***

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", targetFile.Length.ToString);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
```

Comment: +1, here's another related SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024910/allowing-user-to-download-from-my-site-through-response-writefile