# adding download to an anchor tag using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

So basically the html looks like this

```
<a href='test.pdf' Download>download test</a>
```

But I need this to be made in C# what I have so far is

```
HtmlAnchor link = new HtmlAnchor();
link.Href = "test.pdf";
link.innerText = "download test";
```

How do I put that "Download" part in so that when you click the link it would actually **download** the file and not link to it?

Comment: Just to make this clear. Within your example the PDF file opens within your Browser instead of showing up a save file Dialog box?

Comment: It is meant to show the dialog box to save or open. In the Html code it shows the box however in the C# it will not.

Comment: link.Attributes.Add("Download", "Download"); Will het you that attribute, like Download="Download"

Comment: Could you please post your generated html code (inspect web browser page) when you uses C# `HtmlAnchor`?

Comment: the generated code is exactly that --> <a href='test.pdf'>download test</a> now I just need to get the Download part in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `InnerHtml` instead of `InnerText` along with `<b>` for bold

```
link.InnerHtml = @"<b>download test</b>";
```

Edit based on OP Edit,

You will need to use  Response.WriteFile on linkButton click event, you probably look for something being asked in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024910/allowing-user-to-download-from-my-site-through-response-writefile).

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
Response.End();
```

Comment: thats not even the question I asked... But I edited the question so now it should be more clear, I hope.

Comment: yeah, sorry for my question being ambiguos. But regardless, how will writing a file to the website make it get downloaded? I don't understand how that will work?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how it works but it does so I'm happy :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: Place  in your html page, in C#,  Write:  litdoc.Text += "" + "download test" + "";  In handler: mention code to download pdf file, just like :

```
    string file = "";
    file = context.Request.QueryString["file"]; 
    if (file != "")
    {
        context.Response.Clear(); 
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="    +           Path.GetFileName(file));
        context.Response.WriteFile(file);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

where path is the location from where you download pdf file.