# How to compare a session variable with a string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, session, if-statement

i edited the question

it still does not work, the user writes **appendix** then press OK in Login, nothing happens

here is the login (vb.net)

```
Partial Class login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("passcode") = TextBox1.Text
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

End Sub
End Class
```

and here is the default page C#

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["passcode"] == "appendix")
    {
       Response.Write("OK !");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably mean

```
Session["passcode"] == "Appendix"
```

In C# (unlike VB), `==` is the equality operator and `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: Or maybe `Session["passcode"].Equals("Appendix")`  

Or `Session["passcode"].Equals("Appendix", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @5arx: The former will fail if the session variable is null, which is unlikely to be the intent.  `Session` indexer is of type `object`. You have to cast it to `string` to use the latter overload of `Equals`. In both cases, `"Appendix".Equals` will resolve the problem with `null`.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Agreed. I would always check for a null session variable first. "Omitted for brevity" :-)

Comment: @statmaster: you may wanna look at something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873207/force-download-of-a-file-on-web-server-asp-net-c/873228#873228

Comment: @Mehrdad : my old proble still exist ! i have no problem with export to excel

Answer (score 1):

Cast the object type value to a string

```
((string)Session["loggedInUserType"]) == "Administrator"
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686953/comparing-session-variable-value-to-a-string)