# comparing session variable value to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am comparing the session variable to a string to check if the login type is administrator or not.

Code i am using :

```
if (Session["loggedInUsername"] == null)
        {
            btnLogin.Text = "Sign In";
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome!";
            hypManageRestaurants.Enabled = false;
            hypManageReviews.Enabled = false;
            hypPostReviews.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["loggedInUserType"] == "Administrator")
            {
                hypManageRestaurants.Enabled = true;
                hypManageReviews.Enabled = true;
                hypPostReviews.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hypManageRestaurants.Enabled = false;
                hypManageReviews.Enabled = false;
                hypPostReviews.Enabled = true;
            }
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Session["loggedInUsername"];

            btnLogin.Text = "Sign Out";
        }
```

So first I am checking if any user has logged in or not. If the user logs in successfully, the session variable "loggedInUsername" will have the value of the username. If the "loggedInUsername" session variable is not empty, it will check "loggedInUserType" session variable for the type of the logged in user.

Here comes the weird thing, the value of the "loggedInUserType" is exactly "Administrator" without the "", at the if function where I am comparing the session variable to the string "Administrator" is being skipped and goes to the else.

All session variables are getting values when the user logs in.

Below is the data which I am using to login and this record is the only record which have a type of "Administrator".

[link to image](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4471/37860626.png)

Is there any other method to compare a session variable to a string

Comment: How do you mean it's being skipped?  Is it going into the else statement?  It's probably a casting issue.  Try either Object.ReferenceEquals(a,b) or "Administrator".Equals(Session["..."])

Comment: Use a [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the object type value to a string

```
((string)Session["loggedInUserType"]) == "Administrator"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

`if(Convert.ToString(Session["loggedInUserType"]) == "Administrator) ...`

Comment: This method also works :) but I dont know if i can mark 2 answers xD

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Session["loggedInUserType"].ToString().Trim()
        .Equals("Administrator", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Session` collection returns values of type `Object`, so when you compare that to a string you will be comparing the values of the object references, not comparing the string values.

Cast the object reference to `string`:

```
if (((string)Session["loggedInUserType"]) == "Administrator")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all whitespace has been trimmed from the end of the Session["loggedInUserType"]?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Session["loggedInUserType"].ToString() == "Administrator")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
string session = (string)Session["loggedInUserType"]

if (session == "Administrator")
```

or your `Session` can be in a specific class with getters.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Convert.ToString(Session["loggedInUserType"]) == "Administrator)
```

In this way, no need to check null value becuase Convert.ToString handle Null value return "" empty string