# Downloadinf a pdf in new window without redirecting

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, http-redirect

I have an aspx page which has several controls. When I click a button on this page,
I need to get the values of the textbox and dropdowns and do some processing and pass it on to another aspx page. The second aspx will do further processing and generate a pdf to download.
I don't want the user to be redirected to the second page. I simply want the pdf download to appear in a new window. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873207/force-download-of-a-file-on-web-server-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` http header and return the pdf directly.

Like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.WriteFile(filePath + fileName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Note: Don't set the `Content-Disposition` to `application/pdf` as this is recognized by many browsers and they will try to open it with the pdf-reader embedded in the browser.

**How to post to second page on button click?**

Set the PostbackUrl on your button click like this:

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="Button1" 
  PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

You can read values from your current page on target page by accessing the controls using the `PreviousPage` property as follows:

```
TextBox SourceTextBox = 
    (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
if (SourceTextBox != null)
{
    Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: how do I pass the data from the first aspx to the second aspx page and then start the download from the second aspx?

Comment: I want the pdf download to happen in a NEW window. Not the same window.

Comment: Do you want it to download? or open in a new window?