# How to enable the UI back once download has started in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, user-interface, download

I am implementing a export to excel functionality via ASP.net.  i have a button control on a page.  when i click the button, the control goes to the click event of the button.  there i make a call to stored procedure to get the excel data.  In Click event (codebeind) i have the below to code to download the data in excel file.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", "Report"))
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Response.Write("a,b,c") - sample output from SP.
Response.Flush();
```

All these works fine.  the issue is - sometimes the procedure takes long time to execute, so in order to avoid the user messing up with UI untill the download starts, i have a javascript code to disable the UI when the download button is clicked.  This is also working fine.  but i am not able to call any javascript code to re-enable to UI, once the download has started or just before download starts.  when i try to render a script before response.clear(in above code) and give response.flush, it gives me a error that i cannot change the response header once it is sent to client.  how can i achieve this functionality?

**Summary of question?**
i want to disable the UI from the time user has clicked on download button and till the actual download starts.  once the download starts, i want to enable the UI back.  How can i achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try document ready JQuery event to re-enable the UI ? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I know abt document.ready, not sure how to use it in this context though...

Comment: In the document.ready just re-enable your UI (since its safe to assume on document reload the file upload is completed).  Or take a look at this post it gives you feeling of AJAX file download. So there will be no need for you to even disable or re-enable controls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953840/start-file-download-by-client-from-javascript-call-in-c-asp-net-page/15961851#15961851

Comment: My click event looks like this

btn_click()
{
1. make call to sp. Get the data. for , seperated string.
2. change the response header.
3. response.write the comma seperated string.  This starts the download.
}

i want to trigger a javascript code after #1 and before #2.
the problem is with above code, none of javascript is getting fired.
even document.ready
if i comment #2, javascript is getting fired.

i cannot use iframes because, the sp returns 90,000X50 rows.
so i cannot transfer the reader from one page to iframe.  cannot use dataset as it throws memory exp.

Appreciate the help, thanks.