# C# boolean function is returning an object from server to client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, signalr

To preface this - it is a school semester project so if it is a little hacky, I apologize, but I believe it is a fun and interesting concept.

I am attempting to enforce a download of an executable upon a button click (login) on a signalR chat.  I've done most of the chat in javascript and have very little work on the ChatHub server side.

So I've crafted the Javascript as such that when a user checks the 'Secure Chat' checkbox, I enforce a download of an executable (which runs some python forensic scripts):

```
 $("#btnStartChat").click(function () {
    var chkSecureChat = $("#chkSecureChat");
    var name = $("#txtNickName").val();
    var proceedLogin = false;

    if (chkSecureChat.is(":checked")) {
        proceedLogin = chatHub.server.secureLogin();
        isSecureChat = true;
    } else {
        proceedLogin = true;
    }
```

The `chatHub.server.secureLogin` bit calls a function I created on the server side in C# as below:

```
    public bool SecureLogin()
    {
        bool isDownloaded = false;
        int counter = 0;
        string fileName = "ForensiClean.exe";
        string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string downloadPath = (userPath + "\\Downloads\\" + fileName);

        // try three times
        while(isDownloaded == false && counter < 3)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(downloadPath))
            {
                isDownloaded = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counter = enforceDownload(counter, fileName, downloadPath);
            }
        }
        return isDownloaded;
    }

    public int enforceDownload(int count, string fileName, string path)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://myURL/Executable/" + fileName), path);

        count++;
        return count;
    }
```

Both functions seem pretty straight-forward - I see if it's already been downloaded, if not I enforce the download.  It works while in development.  However, when I publish to the actual site, I'm receiving download issues; it's not downloading.

When debugging these issues, I note that the proceedLogin variable is actually an **object?!?!** (as shown in the image).  Please help with any ideas, I'm stumped.

[image: why is it an object?]

Comment: One small notation, you check if the file exists on the server, not if the file exists on the client. Because the C# code is executed on the server.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing @SynerCoder, the `System.IO.File.Exists` check is in the C# code.

Comment: Here's the live site with @Cerbrus's suggestion: http://chat.adamschaal.com.

Comment: If you mean to have the server download the `ForensiClean.exe` then your current code is correct.

Comment: I want the client to download the .exe from my server @SynerCode.  I think I understand your previous comment now.  Do you know the best way to go about this?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `proceedLogin` is a promise object.

Try this:

```
if (chkSecureChat.is(":checked")) {
    chatHub.server.secureLogin().then(function(response){
        proceedLogin = response;
        isSecureChat = true;
    });
} else {
    proceedLogin = true;
}
```

Comment: That does seem like the correct way to go @Cerbrus, in fact I tried that, but it's still not giving me the proper response.  Here's the actual live site with your change:  http://chat.adamschaal.com.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, then I'm not really sure what the problem is. It isn't executing the code in the callback?

Comment: It does when I'm running it from Visual Studio - but I'm not sure why it's not working in production.

Comment: Is it still cached? So it does work when ran from VS?

Comment: It does work when run from VS.  It downloads the *.exe to C:/USER/Downloads/

Comment: No console errors.  You can see yourself at chat.adamschaal.com.  Just check the secure login, type in username, don't worry about password and hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue, by moving all of my download code into JS per:  [Start file download by client from Javascript call in C#/ASP.NET page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953840/start-file-download-by-client-from-javascript-call-in-c-asp-net-page)  It is, after all, a school project  - so I gotta get moving on it.

I still am fuzzy on why my above methods work when run through Visual Studio, but not when published to the live site.  Thank you @Cerbrus and @SynerCoder for your responses.