# Can't make my application available on a website (through IE)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've written a simple console application in VS what users should retrieve from a website. In IE I'm able to download by right-click -> 'Save target as...', but a simple click on the link drops me the below error. 
[image]

I've "googled" around and it seems there is no reliable way to force the download and skip the choice of direct running.

Is it possible that my app has some signature or security issues? How can I avoid this error?

***edit**: It's just a standalone program, not an installer.

***edit2**: Not a duplicate, it has to work on a static html page.

Comment: "*Is it possible that my app has some signature or security issues*" - Well assuming it hasn't been digitally signed, yes it will have.

Comment: No, it's not. I have no such certificate to sign it.

Comment: Check the event viewer logs . You'll get more details there.

Comment: Maybe you can change the MIME type of the link, so each clic acts as a right-click -> download

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force download of a file on web server - ASP .NET C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873207/force-download-of-a-file-on-web-server-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: CodeCaster There is only solution with asp.net, I need a working link on a simple and static html page.

Comment: Can't find any related entry in the event log, checked all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing ClickOnce manifest signature I don't get the error, and I can download it without any issues.