# javascript - make browser send PDF file to download folder

Tags: javascript, download, blazor-webassembly

How do I send a PDF file I am downloading from a server to the browser's download area instead of opening it in a browser window?

I am working with C# in Blazor. This is my current code, which I need to modify, but don't know how to (ofc I googled before asking here):

```cs
    async void DownloadDocument(string apiURL, Guid ID)
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("open", $"{apiURL}/GetPDF/{ID}", "_blank");
    }
```

The server returns a FileStreamResult here and the browser shows the file in a new tab. I want it to send it to its downloads folder instead.

Comment: You can't control this. It's per-browser settings. Some can open PDF in browsers, other can't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force download of a file on web server - ASP .NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873207/force-download-of-a-file-on-web-server-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking a JS Function called "open" with two params. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Try creating your own JS download function inside of a script file / tag and invoking it.

The crucial part to save a file in the downloads folder is to set the `download` attribute of the `a` tag.
It could look something like this.

inside `wwwroot/index.html`:

```
<script>
    window.downloadFile = (fileName, pdfData) => {
        const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfData}`;
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
        downloadLink.remove();
    }
</script>
```

and in your blazor component:

```
async void DownloadDocument(string apiURL, Guid ID)
{
        // call your api to download the file you want to download
        var response = await Http.GetAsync($"{apiURL}/GetPDF/{ID}"));
        // convert to base64
        var pdfExportBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var pdfExportB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfExportBytes);
        // invoke js download
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFile", "FileName", pdfExportB64);
}
```

The file will still be opened if configured so in the users browser, but it will also be stored in the download folder.